# Is it possible to design a circuit that would allow a discharged battery to be paired with a charged one?

Tags: circuit-design

I'm not an electrical engineer.

I know that if you pair a discharged battery with a charged one it would cause a lot of heat (li-po).

Is it possible to make a circuit that would solve this issue?

I do not need a circuit, I'll learn, just don't want to learn about it if its a dead end.

Edit: my apologies. I forgot to mention that the battery needs to be fully operational at full capacity.

Comment: A helpful search term: charge balancing

Comment: Do you want the dead one to be charged, or do you just want your device to run from whichever one is charged?

Comment: One way is to run each output thru a Schottky diode, whichever one has the higher voltage will be the one to supply current to the load.  The diodes prevent the higher charged one from backfeeding into the lower charged one.

Comment: It can be solved with circuits but it will never be worth the trouble or expense (in my opinion). The easiest thing is to design a circuit that draws from the higher-voltage battery until the two batteries are at equal voltage, then draw from both in parallel.

Comment: That is correct. Exactly my toughts.

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fg9l9e.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Another option with even less voltage drop is the "ideal diode" which combines the low Rds of a MOSFET with the diode, see LTC4358 as an example.  https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/4358fa.pdf